# why when i use tracert in powershell,it doesn't return complete reponse?

Tags: ip, timeout, traceroute

i use tracert in power shell,but it can not show all path,some parts talks Request timed out.

```
Tracing route to google.com [216.58.212.78]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    33 ms    33 ms    32 ms  172.31.4.1
  2    33 ms    33 ms    32 ms  192.168.160.2
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19   173 ms   168 ms   169 ms  216.58.212.78

Trace complete.
```

i set **hops to 200,300**,Request **timed out  to 3,5,10** second but it is same before,
how i can tracert that has complete reponse?
thanks for reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not look Powershell-related at all. Instead, it looks like your network (after 192.168.160.2) is filtering at least the *[ICMP Time exceeded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded)* responses, which is what [tracert / traceroute relies upon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute#Implementation) to generate the routing path trace.

It does not matter what traceroute implementation you are using or how you tweak the parameters of the call - your network administrators have broken the network for you, most likely due to the misconception that [ICMP is evil](https://serverfault.com/a/340280/76595).

Comment: thanks very much you rescued me  from dizzy.i will test it with psiphon

Comment: with filter break  it has same response,what solution for overcome this!!!!!????

Comment: @stackprogramer oh, I see, it's one of *those* networks. I am not familiar with psiphon, but according to their docs, you should be able to use traceroute in "VPN" mode which is establishing an L2TP tunnel. If it does not work either, try a different VPN tunnel solution.